# JQuery .before is not a function in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So i have this code:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var ad = document.getElementById('add');//where 'add' is a div with that id.
ad.before(div);
```

My problem it's that this is working fine in firefox but in chrome it says :

**Uncaught TypeError: ad.before is not a function**

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thank you everyone. I'm so new in jquery and js that and i can't even differentiate between them.

Comment: You'd need to actually use jQuery in order... to use jQuery.

Comment: I think you should go through https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one of the DOM methods appendChild and insertBefore;

```
parentNode.insertBefore(newChild, refChild)
```

You can check the [documentations](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery in order to actually use jQuery.

`before` docs state:

> This is an experimental technology
>   Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.

You either want `insertBefore` or to actually use jQuery.